# Setting GCC 5.2.0 compiler as default OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, fortran

I am not familiar with fortran compilers.
I have installed GCC 5.2.0 previously on my mac. 
However, it would appear that my gcc version is still 4.9.0

```
gcc -v
```

Using built-in specs.

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20130811/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 20130811 (experimental) (GCC) 

brew upgrade gcc
Error: gcc 5.2.0 already installed
```

My bash profile already has: 
    `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
as I get

```
echo "PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\""
```

Comment: When you say default, are you just talking about the command line?

Comment: What's wrong with `clang` that comes with the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: @trojanfoe Probably because clang is for C and C++ (and Objective-C I'm guessing), and not for Fortran.

Comment: Ella you can add code formatting by `` for inline formatting and 4 spaces before code snippets with a blank line preceding the snuppet

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah yes; of course.

Comment: GCC version 4.9.0 doesn't support open mp for fortran, so i need to use 5.2.0. How can i make it that the version 5.2.0 is always used rather than 4.9.0.

Comment: @EllaChislett gcc 4.9 does support OpenMP for Fortran (perhaps not the newest OpenMP standard, but it does support it).  How did you install gcc 5.2 (macports, homebrew, manually, etc)?

Comment: What does `which gcc` output

Comment: Try `type -a gcc` to show all the different `gcc` programs in your PATH.